# custom collection cannot implement IEnumerable<T>

Tags: c#, linked-list, ienumerable

So I have a generic class `Node<T>` which looks like this. It just hold the value and the reference to the next `Node<T>`

```
public class Node<T>
{
    public T Value { get; set; }
    public Node<T> Next { get; set; }

    // Some Methods go here
}
```

There's another class called `CustomLinkedList<T>` which looks like this

```
public class CustomLinkedList<T> : IEnumerable<T>
{
    Node<T> m_first;
    Node<T> m_current;
    int m_length;

    public CustomLinkedList()
    {
        m_first = new Node<T>();
        m_current = m_first;
        m_length = 0;
    }

    // Adding, removing and other methods go here
}
```

Baisically `CustomLinkedList<T>` is the collection of `Node<T>`s. This is just a challenge to myself to build a collection like `LinkedList<T>` (At least what I think of it to be). The code bellow shows the example of how I implemented the adding functionality.

```
public void AddLast(T value)
{
    m_current.Value = value;
    m_current.Next = new Node<T>();
    m_current = m_current.Next;
    m_length++;
}

public void AddFirst(T value)
{
    Node<T> newFirst = new Node<T>();
    newFirst.Value = value;
    newFirst.Next = m_first;
    m_first = newFirst;
    m_length++;
}
```

There are also `AddAfter()` and `AddBefore()` methods alongside with some `RemoveXXX()` methods. So I wanted `CustomLinkedList<T>` to implement `IEnumerable<T>` and my `GetEnumerator()` method looks like this

```
public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
{
    if (m_length > 0)
    {
        Node<T> nodeToReturn = m_first;
        for (int i = 0; i < m_length; i++)
        {
            if (nodeToReturn == null)
                break;
            yield return nodeToReturn.Value;
            nodeToReturn = nodeToReturn.Next;
        }
    }
}
```

But the compiler complains about following

`CustomGenericCollections.CustomLinkedList<T>' does not implement interface member 'System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()'. 'CustomGenericCollections.CustomLinkedList<T>.GetEnumerator()' cannot implement 'System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()' because it does not have the matching return type of 'System.Collections.IEnumerator'.`

I can't figure out what is the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `IEnumerable<T>` inherits from `IEnumerable`, you need to implement the non-generic `GetEnumerator()` as well. Add this to your class:

```
IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
{
    return this.GetEnumerator();
}
```

Comment: Thanks. worked as expected.